# Playa field in SAEF

Tags: playa, saef

We want to have a playa field in a front end standalone entry form (SAEF).

However we want the related entry to be automatically be selected based on the entry ID in a segment.

If an entry ID is not present then we would have the usual playa field selection so that hete user could manually select a related entry.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the ID is present, do you still want to show the full Playa field? Or just have a hidden input that will result in that entry getting selected on save, without being customizable?

Comment: @BrandonKelly I really do not mind, as long as the relationship is added and the entries related... and as long as it it viewable/editable to CMS Admin staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
{if segment_3}
    <input type="hidden" name="playa_field_name[selections][]" value="{segment_3}">
{if:else}
    {field:playa_field_name}
{/if}
```

Replace `3` with whatever URL segment the entry ID will actually be in, and `playa_field_name` with your actual Playa field short name.